# ImportError when importing two levels up

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to import `noun0.routes` from the following package structure but I get `ImportError: cannot import name db`.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
├── some_rest_api
│   ├── noun0
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   ├── noun1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

`some_rest_api/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from noun0.routes import noun0_api

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.register_blueprint(noun0_api)
```

`some_rest_api/noun0/models.py`

```
from some_rest_api import db
```

Answer (score 2):

You've created a circular import situation.  `__init__.py` imports `noun0.routes`, which imports `noun0.models`, which tries to import `db`.  However, `__init__.py` hasn't reached the point where it has defined `db`, it's still trying to complete the import.

Move the route imports after all definitions they (or their chain of imports) depend on.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from some_rest_api.noun0.routes import noun0_api

app.register_blueprint(noun0_api)
```

[This situation is mentioned in the Flask docs at the bottom of this page.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/patterns/packages/)

---

I changed your import from `from noun0.routes` to `from some_rest_api.noun0.routes`.  You are using an old, error prone pattern of relative imports.  This behavior was removed in Python 3.  It is always better to use absolute imports (as I did), or use dot notation for relative imports: `from .. import db` says "go up two levels from where I am.